# GCD existence proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a domain. $d \in R$ is a gcd of $a,b \in R$ if:

(i) $(a)+(b) \subset (d)$, and

(ii) For all $x \in R$: if $(a)+(b) \subset (x) \Rightarrow (d) \subset (x)$

> Theorem: $a$ and $b$ have a gcd if and only if the intersection of all the principal ideals that contain $(a)+(b)$ is a principal ideal.

For ,,$\Leftarrow$", I'm trying to prove the existence of $d$ by showing that $$\displaystyle\bigcap_{c \in R: (a)+(b) \subset (c)}(c) = (d)$$ satisfies (i) and (ii).

However, I'm not succeeding in proving (ii). If we let $m \in (d)$, then $m = dk$ for $k \in R$. So $m \in (c_i)$ for all $i$. What key question do I ask next? I don't know how $(c_i)$ relates to $(x)$.

For ,,$\Rightarrow$", what do I prove? Do I have to show that $$\displaystyle\bigcap_{c \in R: (a)+(b) \subset (c)}(c) = (d).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Longleftarrow$: Assume the intersection of all principal ideals that contain $(a)+(b)$ is the principal ideal $(d)$. Which is to say,
$$
\bigcap_{c\in R:(c)\supseteq (a)+(b)}(c)=(d)
$$
Then it is quite immediate that if $(a)+(b)\subseteq (x)$, then $(x)$ is one of the ideals that appears in the above intersection, and therefore $(x)$ contains the intersection, which is $(d)$. This is true in general: If you have a collection of sets, then any particular one of those sets necessarily contains the intersection of all those sets. This proves ii). As for i), since $(a)+(b)$ is contained in every ideal of the intersection, it is contained in the intersection itself.

$\Longrightarrow$: As for the implication in the other direction, assume i) and ii) hold for $a,b,d$. We are asked to prove that
$$
I= \bigcap_{c\in R:(c)\supseteq (a)+(b)}(c)
$$
is principal. Clearly, if it turns out to be principal, then it really ought to be equal to $(d)$. So it is not wrong to aim to prove that $I=(d)$, rather than just trying to prove it's principal, even though a priori, it's a slightly stronger result than what we're truly asked for.

Because of i), we have that $(d)$ is one of the ideals that take part in the intersection. So $I\subseteq(d)$. Because of ii), $(d)$ is contained in every single $(c)$ that appears in the intersection, and therefore $(d)\subseteq I$. This proves $(d)=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by definition a gcd is a minimum element of the set $P$ of all principal ideals containing $(a,b)$, ordered by containment. If a minimum $(d)$ exists then $\cap P = (d)$. Conversely if $\,\cap P = (d)$ then $(d)$ is the minimum of $P$ so $\,d\,$ is a gcd.

**Remark** $ $ Viewed elementwise this says that a gcd is an lcm of all common divisors.